# Mysql databse different size after mysqldump?

Tags: mysql

I run the following command to do a mysql dump on a remote computer:

```
mysqldump -h IP_ADDRESS -u username -p DB_name > sql_file_name.sql
```

Just so you know, only the server IP and my local IP have permissions on the DB. It's not the wild west here :)

After doing this twice on the same DB with no changes. I run ls -la and see 2 different file sizes:
first dump = 3320817
second dump = 3321022

What would cause something like this?

Thanks

Comment: Run a `diff` of the two files. They only differ in ~200 bytes, so I bet the difference will be apparent once you look at it. I recommend using the `--skip-extended-insert` option, so it will output only one row of data per INSERT statement. It'll be easier to see which row(s) caused the difference that way.

Comment: @BillKarwin Will do. Is there any chance that inserting these SQL files into 2 DBs in the same environment would produce a different result?

Comment: I don't know what the difference between the two files is, so I can't say. Is there _any_ chance? Obviously, yes, there is.

Comment: It's only 185 bytes. Could be longer date/time string for example.